# Connecting 2 computers

Tags: memory

I have 2 computers, one that has a hard-drive, and one that doesn't. I want to connect these 2 computers and I'm wondering if I can do it without having a hard-drive on 1 of them and will the RAM on both computers act like 1. Say on 1 computer I have 2GB of RAM and on the other 2GB RAM, when I connect my computers will I be able to use 4GB of RAM?

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  If both computers cannot boot to an operating system on their own there is no practical way of connecting them.

Comment: 1 computer has an operating system, but the other 1 doesn't because  it doesn't have a hard-drive. I'm asking if I can connect them by having only 1 hard-drive.

Comment: Connect them in what capacity?  The second machine would just sit there since it has no HDD.  There is no way to connect a machine with an operating system connected to a machine connected to a "No storage device found" prompt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that’s not how distributed computing works. RAM access over Ethernet is not efficient enough to be useful, both in terms of bandwidth and access time/overhead.